# Using connect-exchangeonline PS via a proxy from within C# (.NET Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, powershell, proxy, proxy-authentication

I am developing a .NET Core 3.1 API that is trying to connect to Exchange Online by calling Powershell from behind a Proxy that you need to authenticate with.

If I run the below Powershell script in Powershell it connects without an issue and pulls back the required data:

```
$certthumb="xxxxxx"
$appid="xxxxxx"
$org="xxxxxx"
$proxyserver="xxxxxx:8080"
$webproxypsd = "xxxxxx"
$secureWebproxypsd  = $webproxypsd | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$proxyCredential = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("xxxxxxx",$secureWebproxypsd)
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -force
$proxysettings = New-PSSessionOption -ProxyAccessType IEConfig -ProxyCredential $proxyCredential -ProxyAuthentication Basic
$w=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$w.Proxy.Credentials = $proxyCredential
import-module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-exchangeonline -CertificateThumbPrint $certthumb -AppID $appid -organization $org -PSSessionOption $proxysettings
Get-MailUser "xxxxxx" |fl exchangeguid
```

If I try and run the same script above in a script file (c:\temp\exchangeonline.ps1) from within C# I get the following error - I have tried using C# with PS (i.e. not using a PS script file) and I get the same error:

{System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

The C# code is as follows:

```
 using (Runspace localRunSpacePool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                localRunSpacePool.Open();

           

                using (var PowerShellInstance = ConnectToExchangeOnline(localRunSpacePool))
                {.....}

public PowerShell ConnectToExchangeOnline(Runspace localRunSpacePool)
        {
            var PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
            PowerShellInstance.Runspace = localRunSpacePool;
            var error = localRunSpacePool.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("Error");
            var scriptfile = "c:\\temp\\exchangeonline.ps1";
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript(scriptfile);
            var scriptresult = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
            error = localRunSpacePool.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("Error");
            PowerShellInstance.Commands.Clear();
......}
```

The error variable shows the above error I displayed re: the proxy authentication issue..

Any ideas how I can get this working via the proxy where the proxy requires authentication?  This using C# of course.  Also, we have to use MFA authentication with ExchangeOnline...

Thanks,
Marcus